# Mathematics behind converting scale to resolution?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, wmts

I have a ArcGIS service configured as shown in this  [pastbin](http://pastebin.com/92hUt4dN).  Specifically, the first LOD looks like this:

```
{
  "level": 0,
  "resolution": 222.2222222222222,
  "scale": 256000
}
```

I determined how to convert from the scale of 256000 to arrive at a resolution of 222.222:

```
var dotsPerInch = 96.0;
var inchesPerFoot = 12.0;   
var dotsPerUnit = dotsPerInch * inchesPerFoot;
var scale = 256000;
var resolution = scale / dotsPerUnit;
```

But the associated WMTS service reports a "ScaleDenominator" value of 241904.7619047619:

```
<TileMatrix>
  <ows:Identifier>0</ows:Identifier>
  <ScaleDenominator>241904.7619047619</ScaleDenominator>
  <TopLeftCorner>-1.77905E7 4.643889999999999E7</TopLeftCorner>
  <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
  <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
  <MatrixWidth>3</MatrixWidth>
  <MatrixHeight>3</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
```

What are the mathematics behind this value?  That is, given a scale of 256000 how did ESRI arrive at a ScaleDenominator of 241904.7619?

Comment: thank you for explanation of scale/resolution. I couldn't find it anywhere!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

WMTS assumes a DPI 90.7 instead of 96 as is clearly documented in the WMTSCapabilities document which states,

> "The tile matrix set that has scale values calculated based on the dpi
>   defined by OGC specification (dpi assumes 0.28mm as the physical
>   distance of a pixel)."

0.28 mm per pixel = 0.0110236 inches per pixel or 90.71446714322 pixels per inch.

If you replace 96 in the equation above with 90.71428571429 you'll get the ScaleDenominator value so ESRI used a different conversion constant.  After a little [research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre) I learned that

> ***1 in = 2.54 cm*** (I thought this was an approximation but it's by [definition](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/Inch.html))

Since there are 25.4 mm in one inch then 25.4 / .28 = 90.71428571429 DPI which is the value we're after for DPI.  [Here](http://www.hri.org/fonts/unix/resol-eng.html) is a site which confirms this calculation.

Comment: +1 There are two different feet; you have described the International Foot.  The definition of the other one, the [US Survey Foot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_%28unit%29#Survey_foot), is that one foot = 12/39.37 meter (which, *pace* Eric Weisstein, is still in extensive use).  They differ by two parts per million: a small amount, but large enough that when coordinate systems have values running into the millions or tens of millions, it makes an appreciable difference.

Comment: It is the OGC WMTS specification, not the WMTSCapabilities document that defines 0.28mm per pixel.

Comment: @JohnBarça It is the actual ESRI WMTSCapabilities response that I am quoting here.

Comment: Yes, but ESRI took this from the OGC spec, they didn't invent this, or, for a change, come along late to the party and ignore the spec, using their size to impose their view of how things should be.