# Why are REST LOD (scales) different to the WMTS Capabilities XML

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, wmts

I have an internally published ArcGIS webmap. The Rest's Level Of Detail (LOD) reports  a different number to the WMTS capabilities XML. I checked out a few public services, and found the exact same thing..

Why are these numbers different. What am I missing?

**REST MapServer:**
[USGS Topo MapServer](http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer)

**WMTS XML:**
[USGS Topo MapServer WMTS XML](http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml)

ff[image: Example of REST LOD & WMTS CAPABILITIES]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the DPI.  Notice it is reported as 96 for the REST service but it is assumed to be 90.7 for the WMTS.  See related question [Mathematics behind converting scale to resolution?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29671/mathematics-behind-converting-scale-to-resolution/29733#29733).